# Policy AllowedValues for the SamplingPercentage property of an ApplicationInsights resource

Tags: azure, azure-policy

I'm trying to build an Azure Policy that'll audit ApplicationInsights resources in our Azure tenant that has a SamplingPercentage value of more than a parameterized value. At the moment, the parameter is set to type "Float" (since you can specify `33.3`, `12.5`, `8.3`):

```
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [{
        "value": "type",
        "equals": "Microsoft.Insights/components"
      },
      {
        "value": "SamplingPercentage",
        "greater": "[parameters('Maximum')]"
      }]      
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "audit"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {
    "Maximum": {
      "type": "Float",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "Maximum",
        "description": "Sets the maximum allowed sampling percentage."
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When setting the SamplingPercentage via the Azure Portal though, you are presented with a list of valid options. I'd like to include these in the `Maximum` parameter's `AllowedValues` property.

First idea was to use a strongType (which I'm assuming will prompt the Azure Portal to inject the allowed values based on the type)... I've been unable to find such a value. Second attempt failed in that it does not seem possible to create an `Array` of integers. Third attempt failed when I then changed the `Maximum` parameter's `Type` to `String`, and declared the parameter as such:

```
"parameters": {
   "Maximum": {
     "type": "Array",
     "metadata": {
       "displayName": "Maximum",
       "description": "Sets the maximum allowed sampling percentage."
     },
     "allowedValues": [ "100", "50", "33.3", "25", "12.5", "8.3", "4", "2", "1" ]
   }
 }
```

and the associated condition to

```
{
   "value": "SamplingPercentage",
   "greater": "[float(parameters('Maximum'))]"
}
```

Which lead to this error:

> The inner exception 'The template language function 'float' was invoked with a parameter that is not valid. The value cannot be converted to the target type.'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The following policy rule will audit ApplicationInsights resources which have a SamplingPercentage of more than the parameterized value:

```
"policyRule": {
  "if": {
    "allOf": [
      {
        "field": "type",
        "equals": "Microsoft.Insights/components"
      },
      {
        "value": "[float(field('Microsoft.Insights/components/SamplingPercentage'))]",
        "greater": "[float(parameters('Maximum'))]"
      }
    ]
  },
  "then": {
    "effect": "audit"
  }
},
"parameters": {
  "Maximum": {
    "type": "String",
    "metadata": {
      "displayName": "Maximum",
      "description": "Sets the maximum allowed sampling percentage."
    },
    "allowedValues": [
      "100",
      "50",
      "33.3",
      "25",
      "12.5",
      "8.3",
      "4",
      "2",
      "1"
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is what went wrong with your policy:

1. The type of parameter **Maximum** should be **String**, not **Array**

   - allowedValues is always an array. The type of the parameter is the type that will be assigned
2. Properties (like *SamplingType*) cannot be accessed directly. You must used [aliases](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/governance/policy/concepts/definition-structure#aliases) (*Microsoft.Insights/components/SamplingPercentage*).
3. In a [condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/governance/policy/concepts/definition-structure#conditions), `"value"` will evaluate literal values. Use `"field"` (or the [`field('alias')`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/definition-structure#policy-functions) function) to evaluate properties in the request payload.